# Highlight duplicate rows, but match duplicates using Name field only in GridView in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Highlight duplicate rows, but match duplicates using Name field only in GridView in ASP.Net. If any Name more than one time duplicate means height light that rows.

Below is code for match all rows but I want to match duplication using Names.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                    new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) });
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    HighlightDuplicate(this.GridView1);
 }
 }

public void HighlightDuplicate(GridView grv)
{
//use the currentRow to compare against
for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < grv.Rows.Count - 1; currentRow++)
{
    GridViewRow rowToCompare = grv.Rows[currentRow];
    //specify otherRow as currentRow + 1
    for (int otherRow = currentRow + 1; otherRow < grv.Rows.Count; otherRow++)
    {
        GridViewRow row = grv.Rows[otherRow];

        bool duplicateRow = true;
        //compare cell ENVA_APP_ID between the two rows
        if (rowToCompare.Cells[0].Text != row.Cells[0].Text)
        {
            duplicateRow = false;
            break;
        }
        //highlight both the currentRow and otherRow if ENVA_APP_ID matches
        if (duplicateRow)
        {
            rowToCompare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            rowToCompare.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            row.BackColor = Color.Red;
            row.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

I used below example.

http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/419884/Highlight-duplicate-rows-in-GridView-in-ASPNet/

My original grid Code.

```
 <asp:GridView Visible="true" ID="gv_candidates" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" DataKeyNames="Sno,BatchID"
                     OnRowCancelingEdit="gv_candidates_RowCancelingEdit"
                    OnRowDeleting="gv_candidates_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gv_candidates_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gv_candidates_RowUpdating" OnRowDataBound="gv_candidates_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Batch Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_BatchName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BatchName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_BatchName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BatchName") %>' CssClass="form-control input-md" autocomplete="off" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Batch ID">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_BatchID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BatchID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_BatchID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BatchID") %>' CssClass="form-control input-md" autocomplete="off" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Batch Location">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_BatchLocation" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BatchLocation") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_BatchLocation" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BatchLocation") %>' CssClass="form-control input-md" autocomplete="off" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Candidate ID">
                            <ItemTemplate>

                                 <asp:Label ID="lbl_CandidateID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CandidateID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_CandidateID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CandidateID") %>' CssClass="form-control input-md" autocomplete="off" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Candidate Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_CandidateName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CandidateName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_CandidateName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CandidateName") %>' CssClass="form-control input-md" autocomplete="off" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit / Delete">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_Update" runat="server" ValidationGroup="bulk" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Sno") %>'
                                    CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/assets/img/update1.png" ToolTip="Update" />
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/assets/img/cancel.png"
                                    ToolTip="Cancel" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Sno") %>' />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/assets/img/edit1.png"
                                    ToolTip="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Sno") %>' ValidationGroup="bulk" />
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/assets/img/delete1.png"
                                    Text="Edit" ToolTip="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Sno") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, instead of writing a seperate method to loop through the grid rows, try using RowDataBound() event and color the rows something like below.

```
     public List<string> DupStrings = new List<string>();
     protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
     {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                 if (DupStrings.Contains(e.Row.Cells[0].Text))
                 {
                    // Color Row
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    // Add text to list
                    DupStrings.Add(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
                 }
             }
     }
```

Comment: In this case first row won't be highlighted

Comment: I think you correct, can you update your answer. @YuriyRozhovetskiy

Comment: dear praveen, I am not able to fill color, can you update your answer with full. @Praveen

Comment: I updated my question check my original gridview above matching with CandidateID. @Praveen